# Recursion using global variable in java

Tags: java, recursion, global-variables

How do global variables work in case of recursion functions?
I have a code below. Why does this prints 7 0's as output?

```
int giValue=6;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Demo obj1=new Demo();
    obj1.fnReverse();
}

public void fnReverse(){
    if(giValue>0){
        giValue--;
        fnReverse();
    }
    System.out.println(" "+giValue);
}
```

I would like to know where the global variable value is getting saved, and how the value is changing?
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

It prints 7 zeroes because at the end of each recursive call you are printing the value of `giValue`. Since the method never reaches the print statement until `giValue` reaches 0, it prints only 0s when the recursion unwinds.

The value is changing due to the `giValue--;` line. `giValue` is not a global variable. It's an instance variable of your `Demo` class, and its value is initialized to 6 when you create the `Demo` instance.

There are 7 calls to the method - the initial call and 6 additional recursive calls. The first 6 calls decrement `giValue`, so during the 7th call its value is 0 and the recursion ends.

Answer (score 0):

@Eran described the reason why you get 7 0s.

it is normally wrong to use global variables within recursive method. but if you really insists of doing it then one of way of printing `0 1 ... 6` would be

```
public void fnReverse(){
    int printMeInstead=giValue;
    if(giValue>0){
        giValue--;
        fnReverse();
    }
    System.out.println(" "+printMeInstead);
}
```

**NOTE:**

THIS WILL ONLY WORK FORM PRIMITIVE DATATYPE ( because the actual value gets copied not a reference to an object)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you do understand the logical flow of the program.

*givalue=6; (givalue--)=>5; call fnReverse();* //print statement not yet reached

*givalue=5; (givalue--)=>4; call fnReverse();* //print statement not yet reached

.

.

.

*givalue=1; (givalue--)=>0; call fnReverse();* //print statement not yet reached

**Now,**

when *givalue=0*; //*givalue>0* evaluates to false; **first print statement reached**
**prints givalue as 0**.

Similarly, for all 6 previous calls the print statement correctly **prints the current value of givalue,** which apparently is now **0 since it is a global variable.**
So, the output is **7 zeros**.

```
class Demo{
int giValue=6;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Demo obj1=new Demo();
    obj1.fnReverse();
}

public void fnReverse(){
    System.out.println(" "+giValue);
    if(giValue>0){
        giValue--;
        fnReverse();
    }
    //System.out.println(" "+giValue);
}
}
```

This code would **print from 6 to 0 in descending order**.See it [here](http://ideone.com/Kqukr4).

Comment: I was a bit confused since I thought maybe global values don't get stored in a stack during recursion. Thanks for the explanation